# How to change Jsession ID after Authenticating in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat9

We are using Tomcat 9.0.7 and we have a requirement to change Jsession-ID after authenticating the user.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not only there are ways to do that, this is actually a recommended practice for security reasons.

Here you will find a snipped from an opensource application that calls this feature "phishing protection"

From liferay: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/d9883da1a7df9de7b72d9aa8984e20693ab8112d/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/session/AuthenticatedSessionManagerImpl.java

```
public HttpSession renewSession(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session)
    throws Exception {

    // Invalidate the previous session to prevent session fixation attacks

    String[] protectedAttributeNames =
        PropsValues.SESSION_PHISHING_PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES;

    Map<String, Object> protectedAttributes = new HashMap<>();

    for (String protectedAttributeName : protectedAttributeNames) {
        Object protectedAttributeValue = session.getAttribute(
            protectedAttributeName);

        if (protectedAttributeValue == null) {
            continue;
        }

        protectedAttributes.put(
            protectedAttributeName, protectedAttributeValue);
    }

    session.invalidate();

    session = request.getSession(true);

    for (String protectedAttributeName : protectedAttributeNames) {
        Object protectedAttributeValue = protectedAttributes.get(
            protectedAttributeName);

        if (protectedAttributeValue == null) {
            continue;
        }

        session.setAttribute(
            protectedAttributeName, protectedAttributeValue);
    }

    return session;
}
```

- the "protected" attributes here are used as a way to copy relevant attributes into the new session, otherwise they will be lost.

Comment: do we need to add the above program somewhere in Tomcat Config files?

Comment: this is normally part of the source of the app served by tomcat. do you have access to the source? so, no not config, but to the source.

Comment: @Victor- Could you please tell more about this, I don't see any source file in tomcat directory...the thing is we have a java application running on Tomcat and want to change jsessionID after the user successfully login to the application.

Comment: the source is the one of your java application. this should be applied directly in the source of this application, the one that goes inside the webapps